# How to get selected row value on the next page using jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to get selected `row` id on the next page. I want when i click on `button` then selected row id show in next page. Remember next window tab will open.
Here is my jquery function.Its getting `ID` in `value` var when i click on row  but i don't know ho to get this id on next page. But i want that, first i select row then i click on button then `id` show on next tab window. Thanks

[image]

And here is my `jQUERY` function :

```
$("#maintable tr").click(function(){
//alert($(this).hasClass("selected"));
if ($(this).hasClass("selected")){
    $(this).removeClass("selected");
    var value=$(this).find('td:first').html();
     alert(value);
}else{
    $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
}
});
```

Comment: What "next page"?  How is this "next page" opened?

Comment: Use a url parameter?

Comment: Thanks for response sir :) I try this `window.open('http://localhost/new/old.php')` this will move to next page

Comment: but my question is i want to store `value` of selected row and when i press button then this `selected` row `id` show in new tab window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment you say:

> I try this `window.open('http://localhost/new/old.php')` this will move to next page

In that case you'd simply add `value` as a query string parameter.  For example:

```
window.open('http://localhost/new/old.php?id=' + value);
```

If `value` might contain more complex character data, you may want to URL-encode it:

```
window.open('http://localhost/new/old.php?id=' + encodeURIComponent(value));
```

Comment: hi..It display id in the `url` box but i want this id print on next page.

Comment: @Hameed: Then in the code on the next page use the value that was passed on the query string.

Comment: i try this on the next page `<?php echo encodeURIComponent(value);
?>` but its not display id

Comment: @Hameed: Well, you can't execute JavaScript in your PHP code.  JavaScript and PHP are entirely different languages.  If you're getting the value server-side in PHP you'd find it in `$_GET['id']`

Comment: I have add this code in next page `<?php echo $_GET['id'];
?>` but `object not found error comes` Here is screen shot [LINK](https://i.imgsafe.org/7f5c24f69e.jpg)

Comment: @Hameed: The page you're trying to load doesn't exist.  You have to execute code on a page that exists.

Comment: thanks alot now `id` showing on next page.But it will working on `row` click ,can i do this with `button` click?

Comment: @Hameed: Put the code in a button's click event instead of a row's click event?

Answer (score 0):

The main way to get the information to the next page is through the url

You can set the id as a query string so when the button is clicked to take them to the next page the id will be passed with the url. Then you can use

```
<script>
        $.extend({
            getUrlVars: function(){
                var vars = [], hash;
                var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
                for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++){
                    hash = hashes[i].split('=');
                    vars.push(hash[0]);
                    vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
                }
                return vars;
            },
            getUrlVar: function(name){
                return $.getUrlVars()[name];
            }
        });
        var ID = $.getUrlVar('id');
```

Then you can display or manipulate the value how you see fit.

Comment: @Hameed: What button?  This code would be on "the next page" to fetch the value from the query string.  Don't you *already have* a button to direct the user to that page?  Please be specific on what you're asking.

Comment: @Hameed: Stack Overflow can answer questions.  However, we do not take requirements and respond with complete projects written for you.  Please take a look at the Help Center to better understand how Stack Overflow works: http://stackoverflow.com/help